# How to skip target device in ionic-cli version 6

Tags: ionic-framework, command-line-interface, capacitor

I created a new ionic capacitor angular project with platforms android and ios. Now when I run the command 'ionic cap run android -l --external' as usual the command line asks for a target device (happens also when I want to run ios emulator). In my old project (older version of ionic-cli) the command does first open android-studio/ios and I can choose a target device in android-studio/ios.

So I want the native IDE to open first, like before, and then I can select a device or click on "rebuild" in the native IDE.
I tried 'ionic cap run android -l --external --target=false' false but it doesnt work.

Comment: you should use command `ionic cap build android` or `ios` to open your native IDE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use the `--open` flag: `ionic cap run android -l --external --open`.